# HTTPError: HTTP Error 403: Forbidden or None is returned when defining headers during download of csv files from the links in Python3

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, jupyter-notebook, wget, urllib

Please advise how I can download with Python3 csv files from https://www.hesa.ac.uk.

My scraped links to the csv files:

```
csv_link = ['/data-and-analysis/finances/table-2.csv', '/data-and-analysis/finances/table-3.csv','/data-and-analysis/finances/table-3s.csv','/data-and-analysis/finances/table-4.csv','/data-and-analysis/finances/table-9.csv','/data-and-analysis/finances/table-10.csv']
```

My code to download

```
import wget

for link in csv_link:
    full_link = 'https://www.hesa.ac.uk' + link
    print(print(full_link))
    wget.download(full_link)
```

Receive 403 error:

```
https://www.hesa.ac.uk/data-and-analysis/finances/table-2.csv
None
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
HTTPError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-7-6d016e0bdd56> in <module>
      3         full_link = 'https://www.hesa.ac.uk' + link
      4         print(print(full_link))
----> 5         wget.download(full_link)
      6 

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/wget.py in download(url, out, bar)
    524     else:
    525         binurl = url
--> 526     (tmpfile, headers) = ulib.urlretrieve(binurl, tmpfile, callback)
    527     filename = detect_filename(url, out, headers)
    528     if outdir:

/usr/lib/python3.7/urllib/request.py in urlretrieve(url, filename, reporthook, data)
    245     url_type, path = splittype(url)
    246 
--> 247     with contextlib.closing(urlopen(url, data)) as fp:
    248         headers = fp.info()
    249 

/usr/lib/python3.7/urllib/request.py in urlopen(url, data, timeout, cafile, capath, cadefault, context)
    220     else:
    221         opener = _opener
--> 222     return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
    223 
    224 def install_opener(opener):

/usr/lib/python3.7/urllib/request.py in open(self, fullurl, data, timeout)
    529         for processor in self.process_response.get(protocol, []):
    530             meth = getattr(processor, meth_name)
--> 531             response = meth(req, response)
    532 
    533         return response

/usr/lib/python3.7/urllib/request.py in http_response(self, request, response)
    639         if not (200 <= code < 300):
    640             response = self.parent.error(
--> 641                 'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)
    642 
    643         return response

/usr/lib/python3.7/urllib/request.py in error(self, proto, *args)
    567         if http_err:
    568             args = (dict, 'default', 'http_error_default') + orig_args
--> 569             return self._call_chain(*args)
    570 
    571 # XXX probably also want an abstract factory that knows when it makes

/usr/lib/python3.7/urllib/request.py in _call_chain(self, chain, kind, meth_name, *args)
    501         for handler in handlers:
    502             func = getattr(handler, meth_name)
--> 503             result = func(*args)
    504             if result is not None:
    505                 return result

/usr/lib/python3.7/urllib/request.py in http_error_default(self, req, fp, code, msg, hdrs)
    647 class HTTPDefaultErrorHandler(BaseHandler):
    648     def http_error_default(self, req, fp, code, msg, hdrs):
--> 649         raise HTTPError(req.full_url, code, msg, hdrs, fp)
    650 
    651 class HTTPRedirectHandler(BaseHandler):

HTTPError: HTTP Error 403: Forbidden
```

If I modify my code to use headers then I get None and a warning:

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/ipykernel_launcher.py:3: DeprecationWarning: AppURLopener style of invoking requests is deprecated. Use newer urlopen functions/methods
  This is separate from the ipykernel package so we can avoid doing imports until

```
class AppURLopener(urllib.request.FancyURLopener):
    version = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/47.0.2526.69 Safari/537.36"
urllib._urlopener = AppURLopener()


for link in csv_link:
        full_link = 'https://www.hesa.ac.uk' + link
        print(print(full_link))
        urllib._urlopener.retrieve(full_link)
```

Please advise how to change my code so I can download my files. Also really want to understand what is the proper way of downloading files from scraped links in Python 3 using Juputer Notebooks.

Answer (score 0):

I made it work with help of os.system. Still looking for a proper way to do this, but here is my code that solved my problem temporarly.

```
import os

for link in csv_link:
    full_url = 'https://www.hesa.ac.uk' + link
    os.system('wget ' + full_url)
```